# avoid logging module from appending the debigging info to the console upon each run of the code

Tags: python, logging

I used the logging module to print some debugging information to the console, it works nicely, besides the problem of repeating the debugging information to the console upon the each run of the code. is there any way to prevent the logger from appendending the logger output to the console during the each run. I would be very happy if you give me some suggestions.

here is the part of the code below and the output:

```
import logging

log_format = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
logging_format = logging.Formatter(log_format, datefmt = '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
logger =logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# console handler with higher log level
cnsl = logging.StreamHandler()
cnsl.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
cnsl.setFormatter(logging_format)
# add the handlers to logger
logger.addHandler(cnsl)


import numpy as np
import cmath
from numpy import pi, cos, sin, sqrt, arcsin, radians, exp,arctan, arange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from scipy.special import wofz, erfc 
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

 # current working directory
logger.info(Path.cwd()) 

logger.info("Start program!")

def dispersion(x): 
    """ dispersion of refractive index of GaN and Al2O3"""
    # first order sellmeier equation

    A = 4.31
    B = 0.034e+6   # nm2
    n_gn = sqrt(1+ ((A*x**2)/(x**2-B)))    
    n_sa = 1.74932+200.512/abs(x-90.2285)**1.50651 

    #Reflectivity GaN/Air(Vacuum)
    r21 = (n_gn-1) / (n_gn+1)  

    #Reflectivity GaN/Al2O3               
    r23 = (n_gn-n_sa) / (n_gn+n_sa)   
    
    return (n_gn,n_sa,r21,r23)
```

Output:

```
05/06/2021 12:02:38 PM - INFO - C:\Users\Sid\Desktop\py\data_analysis\Fabry_Perot
05/06/2021 12:02:38 PM - INFO - C:\Users\Sid\Desktop\py\data_analysis\Fabry_Perot
05/06/2021 12:02:38 PM - INFO - Start program!
05/06/2021 12:02:38 PM - INFO - Start program!
05/06/2021 12:02:38 PM - DEBUG - Temperature loop!
05/06/2021 12:02:38 PM - DEBUG - Temperature loop!
05/06/2021 12:02:42 PM - INFO - ::: Done :::
05/06/2021 12:02:42 PM - INFO - ::: Done :::
```

expected Output:

'''

```
05/06/2021 12:27:04 PM - INFO - C:\Users\Sid\Desktop\py\data_analysis\Fabry_Perot
05/06/2021 12:27:04 PM - INFO - Start program!
05/06/2021 12:27:04 PM - DEBUG - Temperature loop!
05/06/2021 12:27:08 PM - INFO - ::: Done :::
```

'''

Comment: Can you specify what lines you don't want to see ? precise the expected output

Comment: What is "logging information" for you ? Date and logger level ?

Comment: the code work fine, but if you look the output, the logging information repeated each time when I run the code, is there way to avoid that?

Comment: what do you call 'logging information" I don't get it, [edit] your post and ADD after "output" a section "expected output"

Answer (score 0):

It seems your logger has its default handler and you add one more, I failed to reproduce, but that could solve and simplify it

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

logger = logging.getLogger()
```

Comment: thank you, actually it works for me, could you please explain which some more details why I had multiple output in the console?

Comment: @Avral try `logger =logging.getLogger("some_name")` and tell me if you get repeated logs ? i'd say the default logger has it's own handlers, and you add one more

Comment: it did not work , I get still repeated logs.

Answer (score 0):

In the shared code, the line:

```
logger.addHandler(cnsl)
```

will not check, **if the same handler has already been referenced by logger.**, and in your case, this must be getting called twice, that's why you are getting each console output twice.

So confirm that you are not calling `logger.addHandler()` twice, by tracing the calls and method triggers.

or, you can use:

```
logging_initialized == false
```

condition to ensure that you don't invoke the `addHandler()` more than once.

And if you are sure that you didn't invoke `addHandler()` twice , then you  can refer to highlighted Note in [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate)

> if you attach a handler to a logger and one or more of its ancestors, it may emit the same record multiple times. In general, you should not need to attach a handler to more than one logger - if you just attach it to the appropriate logger which is highest in the logger hierarchy, then it will see all events logged by all descendant loggers, provided that their propagate setting is left set to True. A common scenario is to attach handlers only to the root logger, and to let propagation take care of the rest.

So you can set the propagation using:

```
logger.propagate = False
```

Comment: Could you please a bit precise about your instructions, I did not get the point?

Comment: Yeah avral, the issue of getting logging output twice can be due to one of these two reasons:  
   1. `logger.addHandler()` is being triggered twice. 
   2. The handler is already attached to logger's ancestors and here it is attached again.
As a solution for (1), do not trigger `logger.addHandler()` twice, and for second, you can set the propagation with `logger.propagate`.

Comment: @Avral is this resolved ? did you try all options? feel free to reach out,  if you still there is any issue.

Comment: Hi@Gaurav, your approach did not help, even I tried all the options, maybe I missed something. actually, @azro method already solved my problem. How could I change the root logger default handler?

Comment: yeah, implicity, the shared code by @azro removed the `logger.addHandler()` from your code, so the mutiple invocation was resolved. To your question, we can use `logging.getLogger().handlers.clear()` to remove the default handler and add a new one to logger. for more details, please review [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820338/replace-default-handler-of-python-logger/11821510)

Comment: thank you @Guarav, the reference post is quite helpful, now I have a clear view on dealing with handler and what went wrong in my code.